# How to set dark mode to turn on automatically based on time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, darkmode

The current theme toggling solution is as follows ...

```js
let themeToggler = document.getElementById('theme-toggler');

themeToggler.onclick = () => {
  themeToggler.classList.toggle('fa-sun');

  if (themeToggler.classList.contains('fa-sun')) {
    document.body.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('active');
  }
};
```

```css
body.active {
  --backgound: #f6f6f6;
  --backgound-overlay: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  --font-colour: #202020
}
:root {
  --backgound: #202020;
  --backgound-overlay: rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.8);
  --font-colour: #ecbf1d
}
html {
  background: var(--backgound);
}
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" id="theme-toggler" class="fas fa-moon "></button>
```

How would one achieve a time/timer based automatic switch into the dark mode?

Comment: With the more solid base now, what could an approach of adding a timed theme switch look like? Btw. at which time(s) exactly should toggling between dark and default mode happen?

Comment: Are you still participating in this thread?

Answer (score -1):

Before tackling the timer/timing problem one needs to get the html/css/JS base right.

The dark mode should be reflected in a class called `.dark-mode`. The rules and css-selectors should get streamlined, and the `themeToggler` should be changed towards toggling in between the two class-names `.fa-sun` and `.fa-moon` in order to get the best out of the font-awesome class-names.

- `document.documentElement` in terms of targeting HTML-DOM via JavaScript equals the `HTMLHtmlElement`-element or the `html`-tag.
- `:root` in terms of targeting HTML via CSS equals the `html`-tag.

Therefore the css-rules can be condensed to 3; two dealing with the theme-related variable-declarations and one applying the variables in the scope of the html body.

The theme changing class name of `dark-mode` gets applied/withdrawn at/from the `HTMLHtmlElement`-element.

```js
let themeToggler = document.getElementById('theme-toggler');

themeToggler.onclick = () => {
  themeToggler.classList.toggle('fa-sun');
  themeToggler.classList.toggle('fa-moon');

  if (themeToggler.classList.contains('fa-sun')) {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('dark-mode');
  } else {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark-mode');
  }
};
```

```css
:root {
  --backgound: #f6f6f6;
  --backgound-overlay: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  --font-colour: #202020
}
:root.dark-mode {
  --backgound: #202020;
  --backgound-overlay: rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.8);
  --font-colour: #ecbf1d
}
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: var(--font-colour);
  background: var(--backgound);
  transition: background .4s ease-out;
  /* transition: background 5s ease-in, color 1s ease-out; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" id="theme-toggler" class="fas fa-moon"></button>

<h1>toggling the theme</h1>
```

In a 2nd step one could improve the approach even more. Just toggling the `'dark-mode'` class at the document's root should be enough, The icons of the toggle button, when and how each does appear, then becomes part of the CSS rule set. There is no need for toggling `fa` class-names explicitly.

The CSS is still slim and the JavaScript shrinks to an easily implemented and registered event handler.

The time based toggling now can be implemented much easier since complexity has been taken from the basic toggle approach.

```js
function handleToggleTheme(evt) {
  document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
}
document
  .querySelector('#theme-toggler')
  .addEventListener('click', handleToggleTheme);
```

```css
:root {
  --backgound: #f6f6f6;
  --backgound-overlay: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  --font-colour: #202020
}
:root.dark-mode {
  --backgound: #202020;
  --backgound-overlay: rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.8);
  --font-colour: #ecbf1d
}

:root.dark-mode #theme-toggler:before {
  content: "\f185"; /* sun */
}
#theme-toggler:before {
  content: "\f186"; /* moon */
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: var(--font-colour);
  background: var(--backgound);
  transition: background .4s ease-out;
  /* transition: background 5s ease-in, color 1s ease-out; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" id="theme-toggler" class="fas"></button>

<h1>toggling the theme</h1>
```